# ITextSharp SetFieldPropertyy with automatically linebreaks and verticalalignment on top

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use the c#-library [ITextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) for replacing pdf-form-elements with text:

```
            using (var existingFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameExisting, FileMode.Open))
        using (var newFileStream = new FileStream(fileNameNew, FileMode.Create))
        {
            // Open existing PDF
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);

            //pdfstamper which will replace
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newFileStream);

            //getting the form elements
            var form = stamper.AcroFields;
            var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

            //replacing the form
            foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
                if(fieldKey=="mytextinput")
                    form.SetField(fieldKey, cancelationText);

            stamper.FormFlattening = true;

            stamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();

        }
```

My pdf-form-template is looking like that:
[image]

The following picture illustrates the pdf-output for the inserted test-**input** of

> *1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890
> 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890*

**Output**:
[image]

I need the text for the form-element **on top** of the place (vertical-alignment) and I need **automatically linebreaks**. In my case the text is just cutted off at the end! I have researched the web and the documentation. There are [methods](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/5.5.10/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/AcroFields.html#setFieldProperty) (*setFieldProperty*) for font-style, colors, etc. but not for my neccessaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an useful workaround beside to ITextSharp. With OpenOffice I could also create a form-PDF-template. There I can set the text-type to to multiline, which solves both problems (vertical alignment, linebreaks):

[image]

Before the template was created with [pdfescape.com](http://www.pdfescape.com), but now I would more recommend OpenOffice because of several advantages.

Comment: Thus, the actual issue was that your original form field `rechnungstext` was not configured as a multi-line field?

Comment: Yea, with pdfescape.com I couldn't set this option so I wanted to set it with ITextSharp.